# Protecting SQLite database

Tags: php, apache, sqlite

I am going to be using a SQLite database file which I will manipulate with PHP. Since the file has to have R/W rights for the WWW group (otherwise the PHP cannot open and modify it), I am worried about people being able to alter the database themselves. I've read about .htaccess files, but I'm not sure if that can give me the result I want.
So is there a way I can make my database file only editable by the PHP script(by the server) and prevent anyone else from editing or viewing the database, preferably make its existance invisible to users?

P.S.
I only have acces to a FTP connection with the web server - I don't own it.

Comment: place file outside web root - all solved

Comment: If you are going to use SQLite database for server with more than one client - you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Dan Check SqliteCipher you can encrypt the database